# Get I18N String in pure js

Tags: javascript, internationalization, struts, dwr

I am using Direct Web Remoting on Struts framework to show some I18N values.

For Example,

>File name = Test.js

```
function test()
{
DWRutil.getMyAlert("i18n.test.javascript.alert",function(str){
alert(str);
});
}
```

In DWRUtil's getMyAlert method return I18N value from applicationresources.properties

**Question:**
Is there any option to load a I18N values from applicationresources.properties to Test.js directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since javascript works in client browser, applicationresources.properties is in server.

If you are using struts you can use **bean:message** tag to retrieve the i18n string as following in javascript.

```
var criteriaRequire = "<bean:message key="error.0044" />";
alert(criteriaRequire);
```